# Remove whole ribbon from list form?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I want to remove the whole ribbon from a custom list form. how can I do this with SharePoint designer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to do it inside of the aspx-Form in SharePoint-Designer, you can use CSS, which is faster than a JavaScript-Solution or a Content Editor Webpart.

Simply add following code to your aspx form:

```
<style type="text/css">
#s4-ribbonrow {
    display: none;
}
</style>
```

Comment: what needs to be done for SP online version, in order to achieve the cancel, attach file, all the ribbons

Answer (score 4):

**Out of the box form**

Edit Page -> Add content editor webpart -> Add below code

```
 <script type="text/javascript"> document.getElementById("s4-ribbonrow").style.display = "none"; </script>
```

**Info Path Form**

From the List's ribbon select: Customize List | Form Web Parts | Content Type Forms | New Form | Edit Web Part

Then Uncheck: Show InfoPath Ribbon or toolbar

Comment: It's **s4-ribbonrow**. You forgot the hyphen. :)