# How to Hide Top Bar, Ribbon, and Quick Launch in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Pere the below [post](http://geekswithblogs.net/venkatx5/archive/2010/11/17/how-to-hide-top-bar-ribbon-quick-launch-in-sharepoint.aspx) I was told the below CSS would hide the Top Bar, Ribbon, and Quick Launch.  However, it does not hide the Quick Launch so I added the CSS called "Added CSS" below to hide the Quick Launch.  How can I combine this to one CSS block of code.  Currently I have 2 CWP in SharePoint that load the 2 txt files that have this CSS.

```
<style type="text/css">

    #s4-ribbonrow, .ms-cui-topBar2, .s4-notdlg, .s4-pr s4-ribbonrowhidetitle, .s4-notdlg noindex, #ms-cui-ribbonTopBars, #s4-titlerow, #s4-pr s4-notdlg s4-titlerowhidetitle, #s4-leftpanel-content {display:none !important;}

    .s4-ca{margin-left:0px !important; margin-right:0px !important;}

</style>
```

**Added CSS**

```
<style>
.ms-core-navigation { DISPLAY: none }
#contentBox { margin-left: 0px }
</style>
```

Comment: The answer presented here was useful and is related: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/119567/remove-whole-ribbon-from-list-form

Comment: I was testing your code, but how can I safe the changes in my page if I don´t have the save button ? Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can combine them into a single style block and only use 1 web part.

```
<style type="text/css">
    #s4-ribbonrow, .ms-cui-topBar2, .s4-notdlg, .s4-pr s4-ribbonrowhidetitle, .s4-notdlg noindex, #ms-cui-ribbonTopBars, #s4-titlerow, #s4-pr s4-notdlg s4-titlerowhidetitle, #s4-leftpanel-content {display:none !important;}
    .s4-ca {margin-left:0px !important; margin-right:0px !important;}
    .ms-core-navigation { display: none; }
    #contentBox { margin-left: 0; }
</style>
```

Comment: It is working! But How can I edit the page again?

Answer (score 3):

The answer above was still giving me space between the left side of the window and my content. I made a small adjustment and it seems to work:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #s4-ribbonrow, .ms-cui-topBar2, .s4-notdlg, .s4-pr s4-ribbonrowhidetitle, .s4-notdlg noindex, #ms-cui-ribbonTopBars, #s4-titlerow, #s4-pr s4-notdlg s4-titlerowhidetitle, #s4-leftpanel-content {display:none !important;}
    .s4-ca {margin-left:0px !important; margin-right:0px !important;}
    .ms-core-navigation { display: none; }
    #sideNavBox { DISPLAY: none }
    #contentBox { margin-left: 0px }
</style>
```